# Adding :focus to list items in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the list items in the following example focusable with CSS ideally to make the menu accessible for people using keyboards. Is this possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/Etr4F/612/

CSS (the rest of the CSS is in the above link ):

```
div { 
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 2px solid purple; 
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
Select
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works great on Google Chrome 30 and Firefox 25, on Windows 8.

Comment: Are you sure you tried to tab down through the hidden list from the input box WITHOUT clicking on the purple box first? I need the purple box to dropdown and the list items to become focusable.

Comment: I couldn't get it work completely, but here is a start. http://jsfiddle.net/Etr4F/612/

Comment: Shiv I don't think you saved your example :)

Comment: I didn't click on it, but I went over it with my mouse.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/peterjmag/EnVCf/6/

In order to get this to work, the parent list item needs to be focusable. One way to do that is just to make it a link like I did for this example, but if you don't want it to be a link, you can also [make it focusable by adding a tabindex attribute](http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex). (Here's an example using tabindex: http://jsfiddle.net/peterjmag/EnVCf/8/.)

#### HTML

```
<input>Click here first then try and tab down through below menu items without clicking on the purple box with your cursor. How can I achieve this with CSS?</input>
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Select</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
.nav {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav > li > .dropdown {
    display: none;
}

.nav > li:hover > .dropdown,
.nav > li.hover > .dropdown {
    display: block;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border-top: 1px solid purple;
}

.dropdown > li {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4f4f4f;
}

.dropdown > li:hover,
.dropdown > li.hover {
    background: white;
}

.dropdown > li:hover > a,
.dropdown > li.hover > a {
    color: red;
}
```

(Note the additional `li.hover` selectors here, which you need in order to fake the hover state on keyboard focus.)

#### jQuery

```
$.fn.accessibleDropDown = function () {
    var el = $(this);

    /* Make dropdown menus keyboard accessible */

    $("a", el).on("focus", function() {
        $(this).parents("li").addClass("hover");
    }).blur(function() {
        $(this).parents("li").removeClass("hover");
    });
}

$(".nav").accessibleDropDown();
```

I used jQuery 1.9 for this example (and updated the event handler to match), but it should work as is back to 1.7. I adapted it from this blog post: http://uablogs.missouri.edu/interface/2011/08/keyboard-accessible/

Comment: Great, thanks. I added the tabindex attribute but it does seem to work without the anchor tag. Did you say you got it working with tabindex?

Comment: Just needed to tweak the JS to add the event handler to other, non-anchor elements that have the tabindex attribute:  http://jsfiddle.net/peterjmag/EnVCf/8/